# Eloquent query to retrieve registered event by a single user

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I have 4 tables like the following:

```
users
 - id
 - name
 - others
organizations
 - id
 - others
events
 - id
 - organization_id
 - title
 - others
participatings (intermediate table for table organizations and events)
 - user_id
 - event_id
```

so, a user can register to some events and an event can has some users. Organization can create some events. When the user logins, he can sees some events that he has registered.
**TheProblem:**
 I want to write query using eloquent (preferred) or query builder in Laravel to retrieve the events that the user has registered. so every single user can registers to some events and sees the events that he has registered in one page. so far I've written a raw sql. I believe it should be like this (haven't tasted yet):

```
select events.*, organizations.id, organizations.name from events join organizations on events.organization_id = organization.id where events.id in (select event_id from participatings where user_id = 1)
```

My goal is: I want to retrieve events that logged-in user has registered. the data will be the event its self and the organization that hold the event.

My model look like this:

```
Event.php
----------------------
class Event extends Model{
    public function organization(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Organization');
    }

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'participatings');
    }
}


User.php
--------------------
class User extends Authenticatable{
use Notifiable;

    public function events(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event', 'participatings');
    }

}


Organization.php
----------------------
class Organization extends Authenticatable{
use Notifiable;

    public function events(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Event');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have created proper belongstomany relationship for the user and organisations. Use the following query to filter the organization that have a user registered with provided id and then join it with events to fetch the events of that organization.

```
Organisations::with('users')
    ->leftjoin('events', 'events.organization_id', '=', 'organizations.id')
    ->whereHas('users', function ($q) use ($userId) {
        $q->where('id', $userId);
    })->get();
```

Comment: thank you for answering. But i don't want to retrieve organizations record. Instead I want to retrieve events that logged-in user has registered. the data will be the event its self and the organization that hold the event. I've added my model above for you to help me

Comment: Then I think you can directly fetch the events by joining it with participatings:
Events::leftjoin('participatings', 'participatings.organization_id', '=', 'events.organizations.id')->where('participatings.user_id', 1)->get();

Answer (score 0):

in User Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function participatings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Participating::class, 'user_id')->with('organization');
    }

 }
```

in Participating Model

```
class Participating extends Model
{
    public function organization()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(organization_id::class, 'id','organization_id')->with('events');
    }

 }
```

in Organization Model

```
class Organization extends Model
{
    public function events()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Event::class,'organization_id','id');
    }

 }
```

now you have to only call `User::with('participatings')`
and it will comes with participatings that comes with organization and finaly that comes with events

Comment: thank you for answering, but your model seem not matches my model. since 'participatings' is an intermediate table that connect table 'users' and table 'events'. I'm confused. I've added  my model for you to help me. and my goal is I want to retrieve events that logged-in user has registered. the data will be the event its self and the organization that hold the event.

Answer (score 0):

The participatings table is a many-to-many relation between user and event `not organization, you can get the organization later by the relation between it and event`.

So now the participatings table is an alias or renaming to `event_user` table which includes `user_id` and `event_id`.

```
User: events() belongsToMany(Event::class); 
Event: users() belongsToMany(User::class);
Organization: events() hasMany(Event::class);
Event:: organization() belongsTo(Organization);
```

To get the events attached to a specific user I'd query this

```
auth()->user()->events;

auth()->user()->events()->with('organization')->get(); // loading organization

auth()->user()->events()->where(function($query){
    $query->where(); // querying events
})->get();

auth()->user()->events()->whereHas('organization', function($query){
    $query->where(''); // querying organizations
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. My goal is I want to retrieve events that logged-in user has registered. the data will be the event its self and the organization that hold the event. I can't make separate query for this